# How to convert PDF-files to PNG-images concurrently?

Tags: java, multithreading, png, pdfbox, concurrent-processing

I have a scenario, where I need to convert multiple PDF-files to PNG-images concurrently. Although it can be doable using Java 8 Parallel Streams, I need it to be executed on Java 7.

This is the snippet which I use to convert PDF to PNG without parallel processing and by using PDFBox.

```
PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(new File(pdfFilename));
PDFRenderer pdfRenderer = new PDFRenderer(document);
for (int page = 0; page < document.getNumberOfPages(); ++page)
{ 
   BufferedImage bim = pdfRenderer.renderImageWithDPI(page, 300, ImageType.RGB);
   ImageIOUtil.writeImage(bim, pdfFilename + "-" + (page+1) + ".png", 300);
}
document.close();
```

Kindly, please suggest some approach to tackle this.

Comment: ... does it work?

Comment: @Stultuske may be with threads atleast.

Comment: Thread pools were available in jdk7. This is not really pdfbox related, just take care that each thread uses its own PDDocument objects, and make sure to use the latest PDFBox version (2.0.19).